# How to set DEBUG level for my code, but ERROR for everything else

Tags: grails, log4j

I'm working on a Grails application. In my Config.groovy, I'm trying to configure log4j so that my app's code logs at DEBUG level, while all the groovy/grails/spring/hibernate code (pretty much everything else) logs at ERROR level.

I only want to log to console (stdout) right now.

After going through numerous blogs posts & SO answers, I still can't seem to make it work. Here's my current setup:

```
log4j = {

    appenders {
        appender new ConsoleAppender(name: "appStdOut",
                threshold: Level.toLevel("DEBUG"),
                layout: new PatternLayout("..."))
        appender new ConsoleAppender(name: "stdout",
                threshold: Level.toLevel("ERROR"),
                layout: new PatternLayout("..."))
    }

    root {
        error 'stdout'
        debug 'appStdOut'
    }

    error  stdout: [
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', 
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter',
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', 
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', 
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',
                'org.springframework',
                'org.hibernate',
                'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
            ]

    debug   appStdOut: [ 'mondrack' ] // This is the package name for my app

}
```

- The above configuration produces DEBUG logs of ALL frameworks & libraries too.
- When I change the root closure to `{ error 'stdout', 'appStdOut' }` my DEBUG logs are not printed, only ERROR logs are printed.
- When I change the root closure to `{ debug 'stdout', 'appStdOut' }` again I see DEBUG logs of ALL frameworks & libraries.

This is really driving me nuts!! How can I tell it to print at DEBUG & above for my package(s) and ERROR & above for everything else, to stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        def logPattern = '%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{2} - %m%n'

        // define a console appender named 'stdout' that uses the above patter
        console name: 'stdout', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: logPattern)
    }

    root {
        // the root logger - from which all other loggers inherit - uses the 'stdout' appender
        // and logs at the error level                     
        error 'stdout'
    }

    // packages that begin with 'mondrack' and Grails artefacts log at the debug level
    debug 'mondrack', 'grails.app'
}
```

Comment: Should I understand it like - "Create an appender, set the root logger to use it and print at ERROR level by default. But for the packages specified further down, override the default and set it to DEBUG level"?

Comment: @Textant Correct, I've added some explanatory comments

Comment: Thanks! It's incredible how I had veered so much off-course, when the solution is as simple as what you posted. * facepalm *

Comment: Yes, I was quite impressed by that :)